# Changing mac php path to windows xampp php

Tags: php, macos, cakephp-3.0

I am having problem in running php in mac terminal. My scenario is I am using xampp which is actually shared from windows. Now I want to use cakephp bake commands in my mac terminal.How can I do this?

I have tried using `export path="/volumes/xampp/bin:$PATH"`
But I am unable to do it.

How can I change `/usr/bin/php` to `/volumes/xampp/bin/php`?

Comment: Running the PHP executable for Windows (that is impossible without additional software) doesn't help.

Comment: how can i install intl extension for php in mac

Comment: That's an entirely different question, which has been answered many times.

Comment: @ Greg Schmidt is there a way to do what i asked.